# Immutable map converted to object after createStore with preloadedState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I have a problem with my isomorphic app created with React, Redux and Immutable.js. **My reducer initial state is immutable Map, but when it's server side rendered and passed to client as preloadedState json then it's deserialised and it's type of object.** Finally in my reducer on client side i have object instead of immutable Map, immutable methods are not working and i get errors.

Question is, how to pass preloadedState to createStore method in a way that in my reducer i would get immutable map instead of object? or i'm missing something?

**collection.js**

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';

const initialState = Immutable.Map({
    isFetching: false
});

export default function collection(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REQUEST_COLLECTION':
            // here i have errors on client side that update method is not defined
            return state.update('isFetching', true);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
import combineReducers from 'redux/lib/combineReducers';
import collection from './reducers/collection';

export default combineReducers({
    collection,
});
```

**index.js**

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createStore from 'redux/lib/createStore';
import applyMiddleware from 'redux/lib/applyMiddleware';
import compose from 'redux/lib/compose';
import reducer from './reducer';

const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ || {};

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    preloadedState,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
);

...
```

Comment: When you are creating rootReducer with `combineReducers` it return plain object. Try to use other implementation of `combineReducers` function, for example, from the `redux-immutable` package, or write your own

Comment: @disstruct thanks, `redux-immutable` did solve my problem!